# Python Pandas groupby and iloc

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe contains data column, customer column and size like this:

| Customer | Date | Size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cust1 | 20/10/2021 | 4 |
| Cust1 | 21/10/2021 | 5 |
| Cust1 | 22/10/2021 | 6 |
| Cust1 | 23/10/2021 | 6 |
| Cust2 | 20/10/2021 | 4 |
| Cust2 | 21/10/2021 | 5 |
| Cust2 | 22/10/2021 | 6 |
| Cust2 | 23/10/2021 | 6 |
| Cust3 | 20/10/2021 | 4 |
| Cust3 | 21/10/2021 | 5 |
| Cust3 | 22/10/2021 | 6 |
| Cust3 | 23/10/2021 | 6 |

I need to extract every nth date from a customer and delete the rest. In this example - every 2nd:

```
|Customer|Date|Size|
|--------|----|----|
|Cust1   |20/10/2021|4|
|Cust1   |22/10/2021|6|
|Cust2   |20/10/2021|4|
|Cust2   |22/10/2021|6|
|Cust3   |20/10/2021|4|
|Cust3   |22/10/2021|6|
```

Sorry for the bad format, but table formatting doesn't work for the 2nd table.

In reality it's every 10th and day, starting from the most recent one.
Tried with group and iloc but isn't working:

```
df_10 = df.iloc[::10, :]

AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'iloc'
```

I don't insist to use groupby at all to be honest, but can't find working solution so far.

Thank you

Comment: Can you also include the code that led up to that error?

Comment: can you provide a real example with actual dates (even using dummy data) and the matching output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
df.loc[df.groupby('Customer').cumcount().mod(2).eq(0)]
```

output:

```
   Customer        Date  Size
0     Cust1  20/10/2021     4
2     Cust1  22/10/2021     6
4     Cust2  20/10/2021     4
6     Cust2  22/10/2021     6
8     Cust3  20/10/2021     4
10    Cust3  22/10/2021     6
```

explanation:

`df.groupby('Customer').cumcount()` creates a count per group (`[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]`), then `mod(2)` takes the modulo to give `[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]`, and `eq(0)` enables to select the 0 values.

If you want to take every N rows, starting from the K's one (first being 0): `.mod(N).eq(K)`

Comment: @YavorI this is an issue independent of the question, you did something incorrect. You must have a DataFrame. What is the original data? How do you create `df`?

Comment: So you solved the DataFrameGroupBy issue? ;)

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this can help?
[Mark every Nth row per group using pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53813918/mark-every-nth-row-per-group-using-pandas)

With a dataset that resembles yours one solution could be:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({'Customer': ['Cust1']*20 + ['Cust2']*20,
         'date': range(1,40+1),
         'size':[10]*40})
n=3 # for every 3th row
df.groupby('Customer', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[n-1::n])
```

´´´